# Cores or Graphics card more important for encoding video?

Tags: video, graphics-card, video-conversion

I have recently been doing a bit of movie editing and encoding. I am using my desktop for this which has a quad-core 2.8GHz AMD CPU, a 240GB SSD and a 500GB SATA Disk, as well as 8GB of RAM and a Radeon 7870 Graphics card. I use DVDFlick to encode some of my video but it is a painfully slow process and only uses one core of my CPU.

I also have avalible to me a old HP server, a DL360 G5 with two quad-core CPUs running at 2.0Ghz with 12GB of RAM and some fast SAS disks but no graphics card. Would I be better off using the server to encode the video, or stay with the desktop and see if I can tune it to encode a bit faster?

Comment: If you're using DVD Flick to convert to a DVD then it's probably encoding to MPEG in which case a graphics card won't be used in the process. With the exception of CUDA or ATI's equivalent, nothing really uses graphics card acceleration yet as the quality output is too unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends, does whatever you're encoding with support CUDA (Or whatever ATI's version of that is)? If so, GPU is normally better (By quite a bit), if not, CPU, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It depends 100% on the software. Some software is best with 1 core cranked way up! Others are multithreaded and the more cores that can chew at it the better. Other software can use the GPU and really pull ahead. Looking at DVDFlick, I think the more cores the better. 
http://www.dvdflick.net/download.php

Of course, it might not handle it all that much better with more cores, and the speed difference between the server processors (2GHz vs 2.8GHz) might have the opposite effect. Worth testing out though.